# Event Custom Post Type Title show by upcoming Event Dates

Tags: custom-post-types, theme-development

I've few Custom Post Type "Events" on different dates. Event Date is coming from Metabox.
Example:

Event Title 1 
- Event Date: 20-10-06

Event Title 2 
- Event Date: 20-03-26

Event Title 3 
- Event Date: 20-01-19

Event Title 4 
- Event Date: 20-06-12

Event Title 5 
- Event Date: 20-12-10

I need to arrange those Post Titles by latest upcoming event dates. 
It should be like this: 
Event Title 3
Event Title 2 
Event Title 4 
Event Title 1 
Event Title 5

I've made my query like this:

```
  $args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => 5,                        
    'order'            => 'DESC',                          
    'meta_key'         => '_event_date',                          
    'orderby'          => 'meta_value',
    'post_type'        => 'events'
    );


   $args2 = array (
      'post_type'               => 'events',
      'posts_per_page'          => 3,
      'post__not_in'            => $do_not_duplicate,
      'offset'                  => '3',

      'order'                   => 'DESC',                          
      'meta_key'                => '_event_date',                          
      'orderby'                 => 'meta_value',

      );
```

**NOTE: I've two queries there for two Blocks( Left Block 3 Posts, Right Block 3 Posts). I need to show latest upcoming events on left side and those events PAST shows on right side by Post date order.**